# Javascript class inheritance weird behavior

Tags: javascript

I have a class Question and its sub class

```
    var Question = function(id, text){
        this.id = id;
        this.text = text;
}

Question.prototype.Display = function(){
    console.log("Entering Display");
}
var QType1 = function(question_obj){
    //this is true or false
    Question.call(this, question_obj.id, question_obj.settings.text) ;
    this.choices = question_obj.settings.choices;
    this.answers = question_obj.settings.answers;
}

//inherit Question
QType1.prototype = new Question();
```

When I change it to the below code, it doesnt work. Can anyone explain me why this is happening?

```
var Question = function(question_obj){
        this.id = question_obj.id;
        this.text = question_obj.setting.text;
}

Question.prototype.Display = function(){
    console.log("Entering Display");
}
var QType1 = function(question_obj){
    //this is true or false
    Question.call(this, question_obj) ;
    this.choices = question_obj.settings.choices;
    this.answers = question_obj.settings.answers;
}

//inherit Question
QType1.prototype = new Question();
```

Comment: You're calling the constructor with no parameters.  What do you expect that to do?

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-03/traditional-inheritance-in-javascript/

Comment: in the first set of lines, I am doing the same thing and javascript accepts that. Instead of the id,text , I am replacing it with the whole question_obj. why does this change makes it to fail?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". How do you call the constructor, what do you expect, what do you get.

Comment: THe first set of lines passes without any errors. In the changed code, I get question_obj as undefined.

Comment: And you got a line number or indication that it was at `this.id = question_obj.id;`.

Comment: @surya: Yes.  Why would you expect it to not be `undefined`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the first version you are accessing function arguments that weren't passed, so their values are undefined.  This does not generate an error.

In the second example you are dereferencing into an undefined object.  If you have an undefined value and try to access a property on it, you'll always generate an error.

```
foo(); // no arguments

function foo(a,b) {
    // 'a' is undefined, so is 'b'
    console.log(a);             // this is fine, you just get undefined
    console.log(b.doesntExist); // this will throw the error you are seeing
}
```

You may want to reconsider how you are using it, but the "quick fix" would be to change your constructor in the second case to this:

```
var Question = function(question_obj){
    if(question_obj !== undefined) { // now you know it's safe to dereference
        this.id = question_obj.id;
        this.text = question_obj.setting.text;
    }
}
```